# alarm manager service with wake lock

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using `AlarmManager` for scheduling things in my app, where the user will select the time and I am passing pending `intent` of my service class then to `AlarmManager` which should trigger the alarm after certain time when screen is on.

It works properly but when the screen is locked, the alarm is not triggered.

I have used *wakelock* with *partial wake lock* option in my service but it's not working.  When I used *full wake lock* then it works properly, so what is wrong with the partial lock option?

Code posted below.

```
public void schedule(View v) {
    AlarmManager localAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService("alarm");
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    localCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    localCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    localCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Backupservice.class);
    localIntent.putExtra("startservice", "true");

    PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), 15, localIntent, 134217728);
    localAlarmManager.cancel(localPendingIntent);
    long l = localCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

    System.out.println("schtm:" + localCalendar.getTimeInMillis() +"currenttm:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

    localAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l,1800000, localPendingIntent);
}



public class Backupservice extends Service {

    public Backupservice(){
        // cnt=context;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        miscallsettings=getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.i("Backupservice", "Service created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        //  PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK   |
               PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "ggg");
        wl.acquire();
        save();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void save() {
        try {
            // here I am writing the logic
            wl.release();
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            wl.release();   
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show me your Backupservice.java file(where you starting alert activity).

Comment: sorry i didn't get u  .if you are asking about Backupservice class i have posted it already

Comment: i am saying that show me starting Intent of staring activity of alerting alarm.

Comment: check this  Intent localIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Backupservice.class);  in schedule()

Comment: You should add a wake lock when calling the service. Here is a blob post about how to use Service and AlarmManager: [Using IntentService With AlarmManager to Schedule Alarms](http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/)

Answer (score 2):

The way that I've seen this implemented and it worked for me is to use a `BroadcastReceiver` for the alarm event. The `onReceive` method of this broadcast receiver is guarantee to wake up the device for as long as the method runs.

I am not sure if this is the best way, but I am in a similar development and this is as far as I have got to:

In the schedule method set the alarm to send an alarm broadcast intent:

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmBcstRec = new Intent(context, MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmBcstRec, 0);
// Replace the settings with yours here...
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.INTERVAL_FIVE_MINUTES, MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.INTERVAL_FIVE_MINUTES, pi);
```

The alarm broadcast receiver that starts the service. By the way, in the onStartCommand method of the service I am acquiring a wake lock, I am not sure if it is the place to do it, but it is working for me. And I release it when the service is done.

```
public class MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final long INTERVAL_FIVE_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 5;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, YourService.class);

    context.startService(service);
}

}
```

In the `Manifest` I added:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.xxx.MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    </receiver>
```

In my case I also have a `BroadcastReceiver` for `BOOT_COMPLETE` to start the scheduling when the system boots. In this case from the Boot broadcast receiver I setup the same code as shown for the schedule method (Setup the alarm to broadcast to `MyAlarmBroadCastReceiver`).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out my code:

```
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = getNotifyPendingIntent();
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
     pendingIntent);



   private PendingIntent getNotifyPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmExpireService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
}
```

Now AlarmExpireService is:

```
public class AlarmExpireService extends Service {

// private static final String TAG = "AlarmExpireService";
private static final String TAG = "AlarmExpireService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmAlert.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    startActivity(intent);
    // generateNotification(this, "Hello");
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm ring", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

this flag will be usefull for trigeer activity when screen lock.

Comment: in my service class i am not starting any activity it is for create backup of data .So this flags will be not necessary i think right?

Comment: so put that flag in your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing your app in Background App Management setting.